# Umbraco Examine - How to handle quotation marks inside search term?

Tags: umbraco, examine

In my language some words are written with quotation marks ("") in a middle of them.
A parallel example in English: "**Wor"d**".
I use Umbraco Examine to make the search queries & system.
The problem is that there are some data that contains the word with those quotation marks, and some data that doesn't - And during the search, I wan't to get both results.
I know I can cut those quotation marks and make an additional search term, but is there any better way to get this done? without making new search terms?
Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an escape character is probably the best way